# Creating Object of class [Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscription] in Powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

How to create object or syntax of the class [Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscription]  in powershell

I want below Client object model written line into powershell

```
       // Creating the workflow subscription
var sub = new SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscription(context);
```

Powershell equivalent for the above?

Comment: Seriously; at least try to learn PowerShell, and then state what you have tried, before asking questions. I suggest you run the command 'Get-Help New-Object -full' to learn how to create object of .NET types.

Comment: I know powershell....the only thing using new-object I am anot able to create object for the class Workflow subscription..so I want to have suggestion what i am doing wrong ...and that is why I paste that line of code which is in client object and same i want in powershell....I seriously dont understand what I have asked wrong  in that

Comment: Okay, then I apologize for assuming you asked your question without knowledge of PowerShell. However, then I'd say you haven't explained your question in a good manner. You still haven't stated what you have tried, nor why those attempts do not succeed (which error messages, faulty symptoms, etc). Have you ensured that you have loaded the Assembly which contains the requested class? It's very hard to help you with only the information provided above. Please update the question with more detailed information and you'll have a greater chance to get valuable assistance.